# Why did the multiple GPU CUDA codes fail?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have the following multi-GPU CUDA code for my first time:

```
int main( void ) { 
    int count;
    cudaGetDeviceCount( &count );
    float** gtt = new float*[count];
    for (int i=0; i< count; i++) {
        cudaSetDevice(i);
        int j;
        cudaGetDevice(&j);
        printf("get device %d\n",j);
        cudaMalloc((void**)&gtt[i], 2*sizeof(float));
        cudaFree(gtt[i]);
    }   
}
```

I found 3 devices on the same node, but there was a segment fault on the second GPU running.  I have a CUDA version of 4010, and compute capability of 2.0.

Comment: You should add error checking to each of the API calls. There could be some important information you are missing.

Comment: @ talonmies I did, but ended up with the same thing.

Comment: segfaults usually mean you are accessing memory out of the range on the cpu. Just print out the ptr gtt[i] before you do cudaMalloc.

Comment: @Pavan After cudaMalloc for the first device, gtt[i] changed from (nil) to "0x200200000"; but then there is a segmentation fault after cudaMalloc for the second device. Note that this happens no matter what the first or second device is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found out the problem. I have set up the cuda profiling environment by:

```
export COMPUTE_PROFILE=1
export COMPUTE_PROFILE_LOG=cuda_profile.log
```

The second line cause the problem. There may be some conflict when different gpus are writing to the same profiling log file. Changing the second line to:

```
export COMPUTE_PROFILE_LOG=cuda_profile_%p_%d.log
```

solves the problem.